# Adding Liquidity to Pancakeswap in Testnet

Tags: solidity, erc20, uniswap, pancakeswap

I need help with my code. I want to create a simple Smart Contract with adding Liquidity to Pancakeswap. I tried many different things, but the transaction always fails.

I Deployed the Conract,
added BNB to this Contract
and then i want to call the addInitialLiquidity function to set the Liquiditypool.

This is my Errorcode:

```
    Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
Internal JSON-RPC error. { "code": 3, "message": "execution reverted: TransferHelper: TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED", "data": "0x08c379a0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000245472616e7366657248656c7065723a205452414e534645525f46524f4d5f4641494c454400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" }
```

And this is the Smart Contract

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/utils/math/SafeMath.sol";
import "https://github.com/Uniswap/v2-periphery/blob/master/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Router02.sol";
import "https://github.com/Uniswap/v2-core/blob/master/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Factory.sol";

contract CWCoin is ERC20, Ownable{
    using SafeMath for uint256;

    uint8 liquiFee = 1;

    IUniswapV2Router02 public uniswapV2Router;
    address public uniswapV2Pair;
    bool initialLiqDone = false;

    constructor ()
        ERC20("CWCoin", "CWC"){

            IUniswapV2Router02 _uniswapV2Router = IUniswapV2Router02(
                0xD99D1c33F9fC3444f8101754aBC46c52416550D1
            );

            address _uniswapV2Pair = IUniswapV2Factory(_uniswapV2Router.factory())
                .createPair(address(this), _uniswapV2Router.WETH());

            uniswapV2Router = _uniswapV2Router;
            uniswapV2Pair = _uniswapV2Pair;

            _mint(msg.sender, 1000000 * 10 ** uint(decimals()) );
            _mint(address(this), 100000 * 10 ** uint(decimals()) );
    }

    receive() external payable{}

     function swapAndLiquify(uint256 tokens) private {
        // split the contract balance into halves
        uint256 half = tokens.div(2);
        uint256 otherHalf = tokens.sub(half);
        uint256 initialBalance = address(this).balance;

        // swap tokens for ETH
        swapTokensForEth(half); // <- this breaks the ETH -> HATE swap when swap+liquify is triggered

        // how much ETH did we just swap into?
        uint256 newBalance = address(this).balance.sub(initialBalance);

        // add liquidity to uniswap
        addLiquidity(otherHalf, newBalance);
    }


    function addInitialLiquidity() public onlyOwner{

        // approve token transfer to cover all possible scenarios
        _approve(address(this), address(uniswapV2Router),  ~uint256(0));
        _approve(address(this), address(uniswapV2Pair),  ~uint256(0));

        // add the liquidity
        uniswapV2Router.addLiquidityETH{value: address(this).balance}(
            address(this),
            balanceOf(address(this)),
            0, // slippage is unavoidable
            0, // slippage is unavoidable
            owner(),
            block.timestamp
        );

        initialLiqDone = true;

    }

    function addLiquidity(uint256 tokenAmount, uint256 ethAmount) private {
        // approve token transfer to cover all possible scenarios
        _approve(address(this), address(uniswapV2Router), tokenAmount);

        // add the liquidity
        uniswapV2Router.addLiquidityETH{value: ethAmount}(
            address(this),
            tokenAmount,
            0, // slippage is unavoidable
            0, // slippage is unavoidable
            address(0),
            block.timestamp
        );
    }

    function swapTokensForEth(uint256 tokenAmount) private {
        // generate the uniswap pair path of token -> weth
        address[] memory path = new address[](2);
        path[0] = address(this);
        path[1] = uniswapV2Router.WETH();

        _approve(address(this), address(uniswapV2Router), tokenAmount);

        // make the swap
        uniswapV2Router.swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
            tokenAmount,
            0, // accept any amount of ETH
            path,
            address(this),
            block.timestamp
        );
    }

    function _transfer(
        address from,
        address to,
        uint256 amount
    ) internal override{
        require(from != address(0), "From not null address");
        require(to != address(0), "To not null address");

        if(amount == 0){
            super._transfer(from, to, 0);
            return;
        }

        uint256 liqui = amount.mul(liquiFee).div(100);

        swapAndLiquify(liqui);

        super._transfer(from, to, amount.sub(liqui));
    }

}
```

Smart Contract in Testnet

```
0xF0e54bA09c3e7E66f414dCE375f5FAE6846041F7
```

Transaction

```
0xa80e9acbf7310de437f41afdf19f9554bdd846c37ad004dc8efbec9c29093cb2
```

I hope anyone can help.
Thank you very much

Edit:
I tried many different things.
Approved the Router,
Approved the Pair,
Approved my wallet Address

I tried to add Liquidity via bscscan. Nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

The exception is originating from **IUniswapV2Router02** contract, in  **safeTransferFrom** function of **TransferHelper** library. This function wants to transfer your tokens to pair contract by calling **transferFrom** function of your contract. Pancakeswap will assume the transfer succeeded if you return true in the **transferFrom** function. I checked your contract on bscscan testnet but it's not verified and so I couldn't read what **transferFrom** function is doing. I'm guessing it's calling **_transfer** but then not returning true when it's done.